# Is there a way to have properties for a Winforms control that behave differently at design time (in VS designer)?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am looking for a way for some controls to have Anchor = Top, Bottom, Left, Right at design time so they would change when I scale the parent form. But doesn't do this at runtime when the parent form is scaled.

Is there something like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`DesignMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.component.designmode.aspx) property to detect whether the control is currently in design mode or not. That way you should be able to set an appropriate value in the `Anchor` property (and other properties as well) to behave as you wish in design- and non-design modes.

Answer (score 2):

You can probably easily remove those anchors with an event that fires on load.

Answer (score 1):

This sample control works like that:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;

internal class SampleControl : Control {
    public SampleControl() {
        this.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
    }
    protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e) {
        base.OnHandleCreated(e);
        if (this.DesignMode) this.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Right;
    }
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
    public override AnchorStyles Anchor {
        get { return base.Anchor; }
        set { base.Anchor = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi nobugz, haven't seen you for a long time, since msdn.